# java compiler in cloud using java ee

Tags: java, compiler-construction, cloud, war

I need to run java compiler in cloud so that i will upload java file and get the output.
I tried by creating web application (.war) and used

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java "+classname);
```

It works fine in local server(tomcat) but when i upload the .war file in cloud (http://www.cloudbees.com) it is not compiling the code.

Is there any other way to compile java code online?

Will JavaCompiler class work in cloud?

Comment: it is native to the machine in cloud where it is running this code, check with your support team and see the PATH variable and jdk installation on your destination machine in cloud

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to this on CloudBees since we offer Jenkins as a Service where you can build/test your application, upload your artifact to your own private Maven repository or even automatically deploy your application on the stack you choose, meaning: Tomcat, JBoss, Jetty, Glassfish or PHP.

The way you can configure it is explained [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Getting+started%20with%20Jenkins). You also have the [ClickStart](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStart) feature where we will automatically create a Jenkins job for you, so you can use it as a template for your own projects.